# How do I randomly assign a class to a elements I am generating in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/j4qcsksy/

```
function random(min,max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
}

function dropDiv(){
    var length = random(0, 54) * 22.5;
    var velocity = 3000;
    var size = 1.5;

    var thisBox = $("<div/>", {
        class: "falling-box",
        style: `width:${size}%; height:0%;padding-bottom:${size}%; 
        left:${length}px; transition: transform ${velocity}ms linear`,

});


//insert box element
$(".container").append(thisBox);


//random start for animation
setTimeout(function(){
    thisBox.addClass("move");
}, 40 );

//remove this object when animation is over
thisBox.one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd 
msTransitionEnd transitionend",
          function(event) {
$(this).remove();
});

}
//falling divs
setInterval(function(){

       dropDiv();

}, 1000);
```

I have made a script where I am randomly generating a bunch of divs along the width of a div container. When these divs are generated, they are assigned a class of "falling-box".

Right now, the "falling-box" divs are black. I want some of the divs to take on the class of "falling-box green" and "falling-box red." I would also like for the red divs to appear less frequently.

I am thinking that I should put all these in an array (or a prototype?) but I am not sure how I should go about it. I have only been coding for 7 weeks, and I am trying my best to learn!

Comment: `choices = ["green", "red"]; choices[random(0, choices.length)]` will do

Comment: see your jsfiddle update:  https://jsfiddle.net/j4qcsksy/1/  . I removed the background:  black from your CSS, and then added a color changer to your STYLE tag

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this below code.

css:

```
.falling-box{
    position:absolute;
    top: -150px;
    transition: transform 1.5s linear;
    z-index:100;
}
```

In above class please removed the background color.

Javascript:

```
function dropDiv(){
  var color_array = ["black","red","green","yellow"];
  var temp_color = color_array[Math.round(Math.random(0,color_array.length + 1))];
  var length = random(0, 54) * 22.5;
  var velocity = 3000;
  var size = 1.5;
//   var size = 20; ---->og px 
  var thisBox = $("<div/>", {
    class: "falling-box",
    style: 'width:1.5%;height:20%;padding-bottom:${size}%; left:${length}px; transition: transform ${velocity}ms linear',
    // style: `width:${size}px; height:${size}px; left:${length}px; transition: transform ${velocity}ms linear`
  });


  //insert box element
  $(".container").append(thisBox);
  $(".falling-box").css("background",temp_color);
```

Here in above function what i did is:

1. Created an array.
2. Then get the random number from starting 0 to length of the array and then rounded that number to integer.If we will not use **Math.round()** function then random number would be like: 0.1486262298191667 So it's better to use Math.round or Other math function.
3. In above function i have used some static **width** and **height** so please remove if you needed.
4. And last

   $(".falling-box").css("background",temp_color);

Using above code i have apply the background color.

Comment: thanks for this! do you know how i would be able to make the different colored divs have an additional class?

Comment: Then you just need to follow this way. Assume you created new class called .div_test_1{some css here} now you wanted to assign this particular class to particular element/class then add like. $(".falling-box").addClass(NAME OF THE CLASS); Using addClass we are able to class and using removeClass(name of the class) remove any particular class.